# Long running Tasks in a ThreadPool

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I am currently working on a MMORPG game and have a FixedThreadPool which contains 4-8(depending on hardware) runnable objects which handle the movements in game.

Here is the run method of the Runnable.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while(serverRunning){
        synchronized (movementQueue) {
            movementQueue.stream()
                .parallel()
                .filter((player) -> player != null && player.hasMovement())
                .forEach((player) -> player.move());
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

These runnable will run as long as the server is running. Now there are many places I read that ThreadPools should only be used when the tasks are no longer than few seconds, but nowhere they explain what is the reason behind it.

If so what is the reason? I am new to java and trying to learn better ways to do a solution hence let me know if there is any other better way to do it.

Comment: The FixedThreadPool is the correct choice. When you have a lot of short tasks you could better use a cachedThreadPool, but for long tasks you can better use a FixedThreadPool

Comment: I get your point so you mean there is no disadvantage of running long tasks on a thread pool?

Comment: Well the only problem which could occur is thread starvation, but the advantage you get from threadpools is so huge, readability improves so much, i would recommend a FixedThreadPool like you used.

Comment: Ok as my threads don't share resources between them so I think there won't be cases of starvation and hence I will assume that ThreadPool is the way to go.

Comment: "my threads don't share resources "...  is movementQueue shared? If not, why use synchronized?

Comment: Yes because the objects in movementQueue  can be removed by network thread when a player disconnects. What I meant by threads not sharing resource is the movements threads don't share resources among each other.